A question of irreducibility of certain affine algebraic sets
Let $K$ denote an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero, and let $p_1(T), \dots, p_m(T)$ denote $m$ irreducible polynomials in $K[x_1, \dots, x_n][T]$ of degree at least $1$. Set
$$ S= \{ (x_1, \dots, x_n, y_1, \dots, y_m) \in K^{n+m}: p_i(x_1, \dots, x_n, y_i)=0, \ \forall 1 \le i \le m \}. $$
Then $S \subseteq K^{n+m}$ is clearly an affine algebraic set.
Questions: Are there easy-to-check necessary and sufficient conditions on polynomials $p_i$, $1 \le i \le m$ that guarantee that the affine algebraic set $S$ is irreducible?
Remark. It is not difficult to see that some conditions are needed. For instance, if $n=1$, and $p_1(T)= p_2(T)= T^2-x_1$, then $S$ is the union of its intersection with hyperplanes $y_1=y_2$ and $y_1=-y_2$. By taking $p_2$ to be the composition of $p_1$ with an affine map, slightly less trivial examples can be constructed.
Any help would be much appreciated.
